# Vue - Make components appear beside sidebar

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

So I'm using `vue-sidebar-menu` and this is the problem I have ran into. The sidebar appears **over** the components. I want it to appear beside the sidebar. Below attached is the screenshot of the problem.
[image]
Below is the code I have written,

```js
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <sidebar-menu :menu="menu" />
    <vue-page-transition name="fade">
      <router-view/>
    </vue-page-transition>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { SidebarMenu } from 'vue-sidebar-menu'
export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {
    SidebarMenu
  },
  data() {
    return {
      menu: [
        {
          header: true,
          title: 'Main Navigation',
          hiddenOnCollapse: true
        },
        {
          href: '/',
          title: 'Dashboard',
          icon: 'fa fa-user'
        },
        {
          href: '/charts',
          title: 'Charts',
          icon: 'fa fa-chart-area',
          child: [
            {
              href: '/charts/sublink',
              title: 'Sub Link'
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style>
#app {
  font-family: 'Avenir', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  color: #2c3e50;
  display: block;
}
</style>
```

Can someone tell me where I'm going wrong? Thank you.

Comment: Please check and Try with this code -> **https://vuetifyjs.com/en/getting-started/pre-made-layouts**

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the sidebar has `fixed` or `absolute` positioning applied. This takes the sidebar out of a normal flow of the webpage and simply positions it relative to the browser window / closest positioned parent. Two solutions come to mind here:

1. Apply fixed width to the sidebar and at the same time apply left margin of the same size to the content.
2. Override the sidebar's css and use `position: static`. Now the sidebar is again part of the regular page flow and you can display it next to the content (easily doable by making their parent a flex container - applying `display: flex` property to the `#app` is a good start here).